# Keras : Classifying names per origin using RNN and an embedding layer

Tags: python, keras, rnn, word-embeddings

I am trying to classify names with character RNN using embedding (similar to the PyTorch example https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html)

The problem is that it is showing me 94% from first epoch, and it's not clear on how to read prediction from it, my code is :

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(layers=[
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=33,
                            output_dim=50,                            
                            mask_zero=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True),
  #tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=64),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(18, activation='softmax')
])
```

So the question is how to predict a name using this model?
I tried :

```
prediction = model.predict([sequences_test])
prediction.shape
```

and its returning me :

```
(5015, 18, 18)
```

now how to check the first prediction?